# I get this error trying to run a build in vue: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I get the following when running an npm run build in my vue project. Happy to provide more information if necessary.

Error: Child compilation failed:
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

- Function

  - lodash.js:14942
    [app]/[lodash]/lodash.js:14942:16
  - lodash.js:487 apply
    [app]/[lodash]/lodash.js:487:27
  - lodash.js:15326
    [app]/[lodash]/lodash.js:15326:16
  - lodash.js:489 apply
    [app]/[lodash]/lodash.js:489:27
  - lodash.js:6627
    [app]/[lodash]/lodash.js:6627:16
  - lodash.js:14941 Function.template
    [app]/[lodash]/lodash.js:14941:20
  - SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
  - compiler.js:79
    [app]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:79:16
  - Compiler.js:343
    [app]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:343:11
  - Compiler.js:681
    [app]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:681:15
  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [app]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
  - Compiler.js:678
    [app]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:678:31
  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [app]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
  - Compilation.js:1423
    [app]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1423:35
  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [app]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
  - Compilation.js:1414
    [app]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1414:32
  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [app]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
  - Compilation.js:1409
    [app]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1409:36

Comment: Probably a typo in one of your files. We can't do much to help unless you can share the full code.

Comment: Posting an entire codebase isn't particularly practical. Are you suggesting a typo in a vue file somewhere? We've tried removing dependencies. Narrowing down which files or which set of files to look at would be helpful.

Comment: I doubt it would be a typo in a dependency, since they probably wouldn't be usable at all then. If you can share at least the files mentioned in the error that are not external dependencies, that'd probably be a good starting point.